# Does there exist within the Catholic Church a church, cathedral or even an altar dedicated to the Holy Spirit?

Tags: catholicism, church-local

**Does there exist within the Catholic Church a church, cathedral or even an altar dedicated to the Holy Spirit?**

With the recent events occurring in Turkey about [Hagia Sophia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hagia_Sophia) I was wondering if there is such a thing as a church, cathedral or even an side altar within a church dedicated to the third person of the Holy Trinity known as the Holy Spirit or the Holy Paraclete.

> In the Orthodox Church and the Roman Catholic Church, the feminine personification of divine wisdom as Holy Wisdom (Ἁγία Σοφία Hagía Sophía) can refer either to Jesus Christ the Word of God (as in the dedication of the church of Hagia Sophia in Constantinople) or to the Holy Spirit. - [Sophia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophia_(wisdom))
>
> **Hagia Sophia** (Latin: Sancta Sophia or Sancta Sapientia, 'Holy Wisdom'), officially the Great Holy Mosque of Ayasofya (Turkish: Ayasofya-i Kebir Camii Şerifi) and formerly the Church of Hagia Sophia, is a Late Antique place of worship in Istanbul. Built in 537 as the patriarchal cathedral of the imperial capital of Constantinople, it remained the largest church of the Eastern Roman (Byzantine) Empire, except from 1204 to 1261 when it was converted to a Roman Catholic cathedral. In 1453, it was converted into an Ottoman mosque upon the fall of the city. In 1935 it became a secular museum, **and in 2020 will re-open as a mosque.** Completed during the reign of the eastern Roman emperor Justinian I, it was then the world's largest interior space and among the first to employ a fully pendentive dome. It is considered the epitome of Byzantine architecture and is said to have "changed the history of architecture". - [Hagia Sophia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hagia_Sophia)

If there are any churches, cathedrals or altars dedicated to the Holy Spirit are extremely rare, if they exist at all.

Comment: This is an interesting question. I've heard of churches named, e.g., "Christ the King Catholic Church", but not "God the Father Catholic Church" or "Holy Ghost Catholic Church".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several churches dedicated to the Holy Spirit in Italy.

Padova (Padua): [Spirito Santo in Padova – Spirito Santo](http://www.diocesipadova.it/wd-annuario-enti/san-prosdocimo/spirito-santo-in-padova-spirito-santo/)

Venezia (Venice): [Chiesa dello Spirito Santo (Venezia)](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chiesa_dello_Spirito_Santo_(Venezia))

Firenze (Florence): [Basilica di Santo Spirito](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basilica_di_Santo_Spirito)

A long list: [Chiesa dello Spirito Santo](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chiesa_dello_Spirito_Santo)

Another: [Chiesa di Santo Spirito](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chiesa_di_Santo_Spirito)

All are Roman Catholic; quite likely the list is not complete. No cathedrals, as far as I know.

Answer (score 7):

There are some churches dedicated to the Holy Spirit in Poland:
[Google Maps](https://www.google.com/search?sxsrf=ALeKk03P4Ie5jpWEKEi6_V3ZOyXitdqxug:1595545957776&q=holy%20spirit%20church&npsic=0&rflfq=1&rlha=0&rllag=51019944,19617181,167789&tbm=lcl&ved=2ahUKEwjksKTwv-TqAhVpxIsKHUIiAGgQtgN6BAgNEAQ&rldoc=1#rlfi=hd:;si:;mv:%5B%5B54.74293055578932,27.298731337419202%5D,%5B49.31714876693423,11.555323134294202%5D,null,%5B52.112487290172844,19.427027235856702%5D,7%5D)
Exclude the westmost one - Armenian (not catholic) and the eastmost one - Orthodox.

*Translation help (in case the map still shows Polish labels) - English to Polish:

church - kościół

of the Holy Spirit - Świętego Ducha/Ducha Świętego (the ordering of words is not that important in Polish due to extensive declination of nouns - 7 cases)*

**EDIT:** The churches on the map are all Roman Catholic except for the 2 mentioned above. 95% of Polish citizens declare Roman Catholic faith. Most of them are not participating in religious practices but that's a different story. You may only find Protestant churches in bigger cities and some relatively small areas close to borders with Czechia and Germany. Orthodox churches are also present only in bigger cities and areas close to the eastern border with Ukraine, Belarus, Lithuania and Russia.

Answer (score 1):

Canon Law allows it.

Commenting on the 1917 Code's equivalent to the 1983 Code's

> [Can. 1218](http://www.vatican.va/archive/cod-iuris-canonici/eng/documents/cic_lib4-cann1205-1243_en.html#CHAPTER_I.) Each church is to have its own title which cannot be changed after the church has been dedicated.

canonist [Dom Charles Augustine, O.S.B., writes](https://archive.org/details/1917CodeOfCanonLawCommentary/page/n2416/mode/2up):

> Titles of churches may be: the Blessed Trinity or one of the three Divine Persons<sup>35</sup>, Jesus Christ or one of the biblical mysteries, the Blessed Virgin or any one of her special attributes, the angels and saints or some conspicuous events in their lives, as, for instance, the conversion of St. Paul.
> <sub>35. God the Father is, as far as we know, not chosen, because of the fact that He is not represented as sent (*defectu missionis divinæ*).</sub>

Comment: This does not even remotely answer the question! Could you post examples in order to make your response viable! I am aware that it is permitted by Canon Law!